# Do we need both "terraform.required_providers" and "provider"?

Tags: terraform

I am new to Terraform and trying to grasp a bit about "providers".  I see the following code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}
```

I understand that we are trying to work with AWS.  However, sometimes I see people omitting the first section and directly using the second section (i.e., "provider aws").  My question is when do we use "terraform.required_providers" and for what purposes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do terraform modules need required\_providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68216074/do-terraform-modules-need-required-providers)

Comment: I am not really sure where did you see only `provider "aws"` but it could be you are looking at how providers were defined in older terraform versions (<0.13). They had a different syntax for declaring providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `required_providers` block describes [Provider Requirements](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/requirements), which is to say it tells Terraform which providers each individual module depends on. In addition to declaring that this module depends on the `hashicorp/aws` provider, your the `required_providers` block in your question also tells Terraform that elsewhere in this module you'll use the shorthand name `aws` to refer to it.

The `provider "aws"` block describes a [Provider Configuration](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration), which is essentially an instance of the provider with particular configuration settings such as region and credentials. Only a root Terraform module (the directory where you run `terraform apply` etc) has provider configurations; any other modules you use will share the configurations defined by your root module.

Notice that the `"aws"` label in the `provider "aws"` block header refers to the short name `aws` that you wrote in the `required_providers` block. This is one example of using the short name to refer to the provider elsewhere in the module, so that you don't need to keep re-stating the full address `hashicorp/aws` each time you mention it. That short name is also used to automatically associated resources with the provider: any resource type name which starts with `aws_` is assumed to belong to whichever provider has the short name "aws" unless you specify otherwise.

These shorthand names are called [local names](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/requirements#local-names) and each module has its own separate set of local names, although it's conventional to set the local name to match the last part of the full provider address except in the rare case where you are using two providers that have the same final name while belonging to different namespaces.

Older versions of Terraform (v0.12 and earlier) did not yet support the use of providers other than those distributed by HashiCorp, and so there was not yet any need for the `required_providers` block that is used today to deal with the fact that there are many different namespaces of providers beyond the one named "hashicorp". In order to remain backward-compatible with modules that were written for Terraform v0.12 and earlier Terraform has a special rule that these older official providers can be used without explicitly declaring a requirement: if you omit the `aws` entry in `required_providers` then Terraform will just assume that this is an old module and guess that you meant to use the latest version of `hashicorp/aws`.

I would recommend explicitly declaring dependencies in all cases even though Terraform doesn't actually require it for some providers, because it'll make it clearer exactly which providers you are using.

I would also recommend specifying `version` with a `>=` version constraint unless you already know that a module isn't compatible with a later version of the provider, because constraining compatibility too tightly can make it hard to upgrade to a new provider version later when you are using multiple modules; all of the modules in your configuration must be able to agree on a single provider version that they are all compatible with.

Terraform automatically generates a [dependency lock file](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/files/dependency-lock) to remember exactly which version of each provider you have selected, so you can check that lock file into your version control and not worry about Terraform quietly selecting a newer version of any provider without your explicit consent (using `terraform init -upgrade`).

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the extensive information provided in the question linked in the comments, the `required_providers` block specifies provider dependency information. It is primarily used in both root and declared modules to establish the specific provider utilized, and the acceptable version range.

The `provider` block specifies provider configuration information, such as authentication, alias, and cloud regions. These should only ever be defined in your root module as including them in declared modules could cause issues. If you really require functionality such as `alias` in a provider configuration in a declared module, then this can be included in the `required_providers` block within the declared module. However, you can only configure one provider in this manner within the `required_providers` block, so multiple `provider` blocks become necessary for e.g. multiple `alias` and multiple `region`. A use case like this would only be in the root module by best practices, and thus the advocated design is preserved to only define `provider` blocks in the root module.